# Pop in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

If the `ESP` register has a value of `0x00050830` and the address `0x00050830` has a value of `0x00002000`.

Now I say `pop eax`, will the `EAX` register have a value of `0x00002000`?

Answer (score 2):

It will place the value at the address pointed to by esp into eax, namely 0x00002000.

Answer (score 2):

In addition it will increment esp by 4, to point to the next value on stack.

Comment: did you not mean decrement esp by 4? beacuse of the pop

Comment: No, I meant increment. The stack grows from top to bottom. Therefore pop increments the esp, and push decrements it.